# Should "So", "Therefore", "Hence", and "Thus" be followed by commas?

Tags: punctuation, commas, discourse-markers

Often, I have come across sentences that begin with "So". Should such an usage of "So" be followed by a comma?

Are the following examples correct.

1. He is very good at computers. So, I think he can fix your computer.
2. When we multiply an even number with another even number, the result is an even number. So, the square of an even number is an even number.

What happens if we choose to use "Therefore", "Hence", or "Thus" instead of "So"? Do the rules still remain the same?

1. When we multiply an even number with another even number, the result is an even number. Therefore, the square of an even number is an even number.
2. When we multiply an even number with another even number, the result is an even number. Hence, the square of an even number is an even number.
3. When we multiply an even number with another even number, the result is an even number. Thus, the square of an even number is an even number.

Comment: On the use of commas, and on punctuation in general, I recommend, as I have before, [this guide](http://www.informatics.sussex.ac.uk/department/docs/punctuation/node09.html#SECTION00040000000000000000) written by Larry Trask.

Comment: There is a "rule" that says that, like *And* and *But*, *So* should never begin a sentence. But people do it all the time. And that's fine. So don't worry about it.

Comment: @slim: **So,** we'll take that as implicit support for **not** adding a comma after *"so"*, then?

Comment: @BarrieEngland Indeed. Trask was a superlative linguist and a tireless and skilled explainer.

Comment: @BarrieEngland Can you summarize the answer to the OPs particular question (about a comma after an initial entry word) in your answer? Otherwise, this doesn't say anything other than give a reference.

Comment: @Mitch: The OP will get more benefit from going to the source than from any attempt of mine to summarize it.

Comment: @Barrie: Sure, I understand your sentiment, but answers like that are not a good fit for this QA site. Users expect to see at list a hint of an answer, an executive summary, so that the answer stands alone. (in case of link rot, cut and paste missing the link, general readability). If an answer is comprised of essentially just a link then it's best as a comment.

Comment: Perhaps you could say something like "[Yes]/[No]. You [don't ]need a comma in your sentences. Read up Trask and if you still have questions, let me know."

Comment: Also see question *[sentences beginning with so](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43273/sentences-beginning-with-so)*

Comment: @BarrieEngland, The answer to my question isn't there in the link you have provided.

Answer (score 25):

Commas are not determined by grammar, nor by which words they follow. 
Comma indicates ***[a particular intonation](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/commas.html)***. If you would use that intonation in speaking the sentence, use a comma; if not, don't. So it's important to hear what you're writing, in your mind if nowhere else.

Generally in short sentences you wouldn't, but if the sentence following the introductory word is long, you might well. Also generally speaking, if the material coming first is long (as it is in this sentence but wasn't in the previous sentence), you would.

[Punctuation](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/IELL-Punctuation.pdf) is not absolute; it's a work in progress.

Comment: I think in OP's context, including the comma reflects a certain degree of "hesitant attention-grabbing" - often typical of some people's conversational style within a group. It causes the "**So**" to linger longer before the "follow-up" conclusion - implicitly there's a pause there that means something like *(please start listening to me now because I'm about to say something relevant to what's just been said)*

Comment: That's certainly one recognizable usage. There are lots of others, along with myriads of individual styles, not all useful. As I said, a work in progress.

Comment: Haha - it'll be a lifetime's work, I think! But I certainly think your point about *"Generally in short sentences you wouldn't"* covers many situations. Conversely, I find it hard to imagine anyone saying, for example, *"It's raining, so, here's an umbrella"*.

Comment: This theory of commas is not particularly helpful, as it simply converts the question into "Should introductory words be spoken with a comma-like intonation?" There are answers to that in formal registers, and these correspond to rules for comma usage.

Comment: There are **some** answers to that in **some** formal registers, and these correspond to **some** rules for comma usage, for **some** people. But in the last analysis, writing does not capture all (or even most) of language, and no punctuation rules solve that problem. You **have to** hear the intonation, as I said in the answer.

Answer (score 12):

The short answer is "no." The longer answer is: a comma is not a requirement but neither is it something to avoid.

What may blow your mind is that the comma is not required anywhere in any of your examples. It is a matter of style.

Answer (score 0):

The trend is away from commas, and I use them where they help make the sentence easier to read, or help the flow. More important is consistency. If the comma is omitted in one place, it should be omitted in all instances thereafter. Useful punctuation is invisible; the reader shouldn't notice it.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** Commas after introductory words are allowed, but not required.

**Long answer:**

As mentioned in the comments, Larry Trask's guide to punctuation is an excellent resource. Introductory words like the ones you mention (also "moreover", "in contrast" etc.) fall into the category of [bracketing commas](http://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/comma/bracketing). Trask's summary of the rules for including bracketing commas are:

> - Use a pair of bracketing commas to set off a weak interruption which could be removed from the sentence without destroying it.
> - If the interruption comes at the beginning or the end of the sentence, use only one bracketing comma.
> - Make sure the words set off are really an interruption.

Introductory words are primarily used to smooth the transition between sentences, so they can clearly be removed from the sentence without changing the meaning. Thus, they fulfill Trask's criteria for bracketing commas used at the beginning of a sentence.

However, Trask also notes

> In many cases a weak interruption does not absolutely require bracketing commas.

Omitting the comma in these cases practically never causes confusion or ambiguity, and it can improve the flow between sentences. So feel free to omit the commas if your prefer, particularly for short sentences.