# What’s the need for the comma

Tags: punctuation, subjects

I’m puzzling over this comma at the beginning of the quote below. Is it another way to make it clear that the author is speaking about two different people - SOME musician and SOME OTHER artist? Doesn’t the repetition of ‘another’ already serve it perfectly? Or am I getting this part totally wrong?

> To quote another musician, and another artist inspired by
> Starkweather, Bruce Springsteen concluded his 1982 record Nebraska
> with the song “Reason to Believe.”

Comment: It reads like the musician **is** another artist inspired. "To quote another musician, also inspired..." The commas set off the parenthetical expression.

Comment: The musician mentioned is the same person as the artist. It appears that the writer is bringing to our attention the fact that Starkweather has trained many artists, and so he supplies extra information (which is set off with commas.) You could just as well set off this extra piece of information with dashes.

Comment: Note that [Charles Starkweather](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Starkweather) was an American murderer, so Springsteen is referring to artists who have produced work based on Starkweather's life, not people trained or inspired by Starkweather's music.

Comment: A comma represents a *pause*.

Comment: @StuartF Ah, thank you for that information. Didn't know who this guy was.

Answer (score 1):

Commas are a marker of *intonation,* not syntax, as [Lawler has noted here.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58939/should-so-therefore-hence-and-thus-be-followed-by-commas/58943#58943) The comma rules are just heuristics for determining where native speakers typically divide speech into intonation units.

In this case, most speakers *would* adopt the change in tone after "another musician," in order to indicate that "and another artist inspired by Starkweather" is a parenthetical remark. This is important because it clarifies that this remark is giving additional information about the same musician, not introducing a new one.

Answer (score 0):

> To quote another musician, and another artist inspired by
> Starkweather, Bruce Springsteen concluded his 1982 record Nebraska
> with the song “Reason to Believe.”

This musician is the same one i.e. "another artist inspired..."

If the musician and the artist were two different people, this sentence would have been used.

> To quote another musician, and one other artist inspired by
> Starkweather, Bruce Springsteen concluded his 1982 record Nebraska
> with the song “Reason to Believe.”

Comment: My intuition is conflicted on this one. Can you explain a little more what is the difference between "another" and "one other"? Don't they sound the same?