# Semicolon placed after conjunctive adverb linking two independent clauses?

Tags: grammar

I was practicing for my SAT with the official SAT questions when I came across this one and was quite confused.
[image]

Why is the semicolon placed AFTER "however" (see picture)?

I get the need for a semicolon to be used but I am quite confused about the position of where the semicolon is placed. I always thought that the semicolon should be placed before the adverb connecting the two independent clauses. E.g.- He went to bed early; however, he didn’t get much sleep.

I also don't understand the part of the explanation where the position of semicolon indicates that the information is contrary to the previous sentence.

Is there a rule of thumb I can use to determine where the semicolon should go?

Thanks!!

Comment: IMO C isn't correct because the part before the semicolon does not make a complete sentence that would stand on its own. My reference is [here](https://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/colonandsemi/semi). I'm not convinced that *any* semicolon is needed, because 'however' is joining the clauses. See (2) in the link.

Comment: Related: [here is a discussion](https://prowritingaid.com/comma-however) about punctuating 'however', which favours your own answer.

Comment: The sentence is odd as marked with C. Using *however* that way is unusual to a degree that is unfair to 16-year-olds in a timed test that forms a make-or-break for college entrance.

Answer (score 2):

Some believe in rules about where "however" can be placed in a sentence or will cite rules about proper comma usage around the word "however."

**Here, though, it's ultimately an issue of meaning,** as the last part of the SAT's explanation states. If you put "however" after the semicolon, it would suggest that "some of the Renaissance figures were influenced by Greek and Roman literature" was intended to *contrast* with "the neoclassicals were not the first to adopt  the modes of classical antiquity." In fact, the former is intended to provide supporting evidence for the later; there is no contrast for "however" to mark.

Instead, the purpose of the "however" is to qualify the preceding remark by noting that "the neoclassicals were not the first to adopt  the modes of classical antiquity." So putting the semicolon before the "however" makes perfect sense.

Comment: This is pretty well spot on and illustrates everything that is wrong with multiple choice questions with 'right/wrong' answers. They presuppose that there is only one way of looking at it and leaves to student  trying to read the questioner's mind.  Placements like that of however change all the time.  The punctuation element leaves unanswered the question why 'however' has to be followed by a comma, when 'but', which in this case is used in exactly the same way, does not.  Some of these 'rules' seem arbitrary.

Comment: [As I have explained elsewhere,](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/603873/470858) the typical presentation of "comma rules" makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you move *however* to the beginning of the sentence you can better understand the meaning and hence the punctuation:

> *During the English neoclassical period (1660–1789), many writers imitated the epic poetry and satires of ancient Greece and Rome.
> **However, they were not the first in England to adopt the literary modes of classical antiquity;** some of the most prominent figures of
> the earlier Renaissance period were also influenced by ancient Greek
> and Roman literature.*

Neoclassical writers imitated the writings of the classics, but they were not the first to do so; Renaissance writers beat them to the punch.