# Starting a sentence with because

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

Because PaymentX stores the user's credit card details for you and sends your server a token to charge the card, if you use our SDK, your PCI compliance scope is greatly reduced compared to the case when your servers were handling the card details directly.

What's the best way to phrase the sentence above? I know an english rule is to never start a sentence with Because.

Comment: There is no rule against beginning a sentence with a preposition. Don't sweat it.

Comment: It's fine as is, but if you worry about silly nitpickers, you can change "Because" to "Since" or "As". (They're both worse, but you avoid the nitpickers.)

Comment: The usual practice is to use *As*, not *Because*. See usage examples in technical writing.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Why would *since* and *as* be worse?

Comment: @Kris It's just a subjective style judgment on my part.

Comment: @Kris _Because_ has a specific meaning which indicates cause and effect. _Since_ and _as_ do not carry this same meaning, so when we use one of them instead, we lose this intended meaning. If we can assume that this meaning is intentional and correct, then certainly losing it is worse.

Comment: @MarkBailey: Not true, both words can be used as synonyms of "because" - [since (def 2)](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/since#Conjunction), [as (def 5)](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/as#Conjunction). The problem is that they both have tonnes of other meanings, and that can make them less clear. But it's usually fairly obvious from the context.

Answer (score 1):

This use of because at the beginning of the sentence is actually not against the rule. The sentence is just fine grammatically. The case when it would be wrong would be something like this "Why do I love chocolate? Because it's totally delicious." This sentence is wrong because putting that word at the beginning changes it from a sentence to a phrase. Because it is punctuated as a sentence (beginning with a capital letter and ending with a period), it is a sentence fragment, and thus bad grammar.   <-- Yes, this last sentence is also good grammar.